# Unable to send mail to a email server

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer library to send email through my mail server with domain name pixels.com .I am able to send emails to all email addresses like Gmail, yahoo etc.,but I am unable to send mail to email addresses which belongs to the same server like admin@pixels.com.Can someone suggest me solution to this problem .Do I need to change some setting.What are the other possible solutions to solve this issue.My php code for sending mail is

```
 <?php
    require("class.PHPMailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use      SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "jswan";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "secret"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "from@example.com";
  $mail->FromName = "Mailer";
  $mail->AddAddress("josh@example.net", "Josh Adams");
   $mail->AddAddress("ellen@example.com");                  // name is optional
    $mail->AddReplyTo("info@example.com", "Information");

     $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
           $mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
         $mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
         $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

       $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
      $mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
     $mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

  if(!$mail->Send())
     {
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
    }

echo "Message has been sent";
     ?>
```

Comment: If you're able to send to other email addresses then it sounds like the code is working as designed.  Maybe you need to ask your hosting provider why their emails are being lost?

Comment: I am wondering if we can send mail from one server to email address belonging to same server using a program

Comment: This is not working code. You're using an old example and an old version of PHPMailer.

Comment: please help me go get the new code

Answer (score 0):

You should update the PHPMailer version you are using, this code would work in old versions, try exploring their [Github page](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), they have a lot of examples there.